# Exception handling at individual rule level - Drools

Tags: java, drools

How to catch and handle exceptions at individual rule level in Drools?

Aim is that exceptions at a single rule should not impact the execution of the rest of the rules.

I know that we can use try catch in RHS, but can we have a control at much higher level irrespective of what LHS or RHS is.

Something like:

```
fireAllRules( new DefaultAgendaEventListener() {
    @Override
        public void whenExceptionAtRule(Exception exception) {
            //handle exception when 
        }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to implement the `org.kie.api.runtime.rule.ConsequenceExceptionHandler` interface:

```
package sample;

public class MyConsequenceExceptionHandler implements ConsequenceExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleException(Match match, RuleRuntime rr, Exception excptn) {
        //Do whatever you want
    }

}
```

Then, it all depends on how are you creating your `KieBases`. If you are doing it manually (without using a kmodule.xml file), then you need to create a `KieBaseConfiguration` to specify what class you want to use to handle exceptions:

```
KieBaseConfiguration kconfig = new RuleBaseConfiguration();
kconfig.setProperty(ConsequenceExceptionHandlerOption.PROPERTY_NAME, "sample.MyConsequenceExceptionHandler");
```

And then use this `kconfig` object when creating your `KieBase`:

```
KieSession ksession = kcontainer.newKieBase(kconfig).newKieSession();
```

I couldn't find a declarative way to register the handler in the kmodule.xml file though.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks!! This works for RHS.  But how to catch Runtime Exceptions at the LHS ("when" part of the rule where there will be a boolean expression )?

Comment: As far as I understand, Exceptions in the `LHS` can't be handled. Even if they could have been handled, an exception in the `LHS` will probably leave the state o the RETE network in an inconsistent state. The good practices say that the `LHS` should only do pattern matching. Could you explain what are you doing in the `LHS` of your rules?

Comment: Sometimes LHS involves expressions such as, `Double.parseDouble(payment) > 0`.  This involves risks such as payment is not a number but a string.   This specific case can be handled not by using a `Double.parseDouble` but a safe custom utility method.    But there is always a possibility that something can go wrong. right?

Comment: **[after reading about RETE] ** To be more specific, in my case, i am using Drools for a bit different case than it is usually used for.  I do not want rules to fired when some changes happen to be business object.  But i pass the business object across all rules in which some of them end up transforming the object state and some do not, and thats it.

Comment: How to add logic to WHEN, i.e. LHS part of drools?
@Gautham, please let me know if you have any example