# Is it possible to return an exception in a drools rule?

Tags: drools

Is it possible in Drools to throw an exception or should I return a String and when I get the response should I verify the String I received?

Example:

```
package droolsvalidation.droolsvalidation;
import drools.validation.Code;

rule "MyRule"
when
    c: Code(code==null)
then
    throw Exception
end
```

How can I do that if it's possible or how can I handle it?

And it would be great if you can show an example of how can I catch that Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, yes, but I don't know if it is recommended. In any case, you can handle exceptions thrown during the execution of a `KieBase` by registering a `ConsequenceExceptionHandler` to it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154358/exception-handling-at-individual-rule-level-drools/49155093#49155093) explains the mentioned approach.

Hope it helps,